# If variable equals value php

Tags: php, mysql, variables, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to do a check before the data inserts into the MySQL query.
Here is the code;

```
$userid = ($vbulletin->userinfo['userid']);
$sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID='$_POST[hiddenID]'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql3)){

$toon = $row['toonname'];
$laff = $row['tlaff'];
$type = $row['ttype'];

if ($type == 1){
$type == "Bear";
} elseif ($type == 2){
$type == "Cat";
} elseif ($type == 3){
$type == "Dog";
}            

}
```

However, this isn't working.
Basically, there are different values in the 'table' for each type.  1 means Bear, 2 means Cat, and 3 means Dog.

Thanks to whomever can help see a problem in my script!

Comment: You need to learn more between assigment `=`, equality `==` and `===` identity operators

Comment: Use an array instead of `if`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are comparing, not assigning:

```
if ($type == 1){
  $type = "Bear"; 
}
```

You compare values with `==` or `===`.

You assign values with `=`.

You could write less code to achieve the same result too, with a `switch` statement, or just a bunch of `if`s without the `elseif`s.

```
if ($type == 1) $type = "Bear";
if ($type == 2) $type = "Cat";
if ($type == 3) $type = "Dog";
```

I would make a function for it, like this:

```
function get_species($type) {
    switch ($type):
        case 1: return 'Bear';
        case 2: return 'Cat';
        case 3: return 'Dog';
       default: return 'Jeff Atwood';
    endswitch;
}

$type = get_species($row['ttype']);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using `==` instead of `=`. It compares the variable to the new value. Use `=` to set the value.

```
if ($type == 1){
$type = "Bear";
} elseif ($type == 2){
$type = "Cat";
} elseif ($type == 3){
$type = "Dog";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using `==` to assign values:

`$type == bear;`

Should be:

`$type = bear;`

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($type == 1) {$displayVar = "Bear";}
```

**Example:**

```
<form method="post" action="results.php">
How many horns does a unicorn have? <br />
<input type="text" name="inputField" id="inputField" /> <br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <br />
</form>
```

**Results:**

```
<?php 
$inputVar = $_POST["inputField"];
if ($inputVar == 1) {$answerVar = "correct";}
else $answerVar = "<strong>not correct</strong>";
?>
<?php 
echo "Your answer is " . $answerVar . "<br />";
?>
```