# If statement Redirect

Tags: php, mysql

I have the follow code.

```
$acct="SELECT acctype FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
```

Then I have this If statement

```
if ($acct="customer") {
Header("Location: user/dashboard.php");
}
else {
Header("Location: other/dashboard.php");
}
```

Sample database output

```
mysql> select * from users;
+----+----------+----------------------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| id | username | password                         | fullname | location | acctype  |
+----+----------+----------------------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 14 | customer | 91ec1f9324753048c0096d036a694f86 | customer | customer | customer |
| 15 | mfg      | fcc66ac1c0e07a00b56b0dc4c0902567 | mfg      | mfg      | mfg      |
| 16 | designer | 230ace927da4bb74817fa22adc663e0a | designer | designer | designer |
| 19 | both     | f6cb3e816496528d4187db53bc66567f | both     | both     | both     |
+----+----------+----------------------------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

So my goal is to have user when they login if their acctype is customer go to user/dashboard.php

If the acctype is anthing else go to other/dashboard.php

For some reason it is ignoring the acctype and just going to the first if condition.

Running the Query through MySQL will output the correct response.

```
mysql> SELECT acctype FROM users WHERE username='customer';
+----------+
| acctype  |
+----------+
| customer |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT acctype FROM users WHERE username='both';
+--------+
| acctype|
+--------+
| both   |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: You're assigning using `=` instead of comparing `==` in your `if ($acct="customer")` - Do `if($acct=="customer")`

Comment: `"SELECT acctype FROM users WHERE username='$username'"` does not equal `"customer"`.  You are actually *running* that SQL query, right?

Comment: You'll need to query the database and fetch the resulting data. Setting `$acct` to your query string will not query the database.

Comment: **Steps:** 1) Query DB 2) Use a (while) loop and fetch 3) If it exists (do something) --- You'll find your answer in [`this Q&A`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16377823/) (and piece it all together), where OP is fetching from DB, and has also made the similar mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i agree with Rocket your php coding need some work.

First start out with the request.
You call the by using mysqli_query and then setting "results" equal to it.

```
$results = mysqli_query("SELECT acctype FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
```

Then create a variable to read each row.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result1);
```

WE only want the first result so ...

```
if ($row[0]=="customer") {
Header("Location: user/dashboard.php");
}
else {
Header("Location: other/dashboard.php");
}
```

"$row[0]" will read the first line in the database.

That should work.

Comment: Just a heads up. First you use `mysqli_query` then `mysql_fetch_row` (Note the **i**)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    $query = "SELECT acctype FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
    if($resultSet = $mysqli->query($query)){
      while($col = $resultSet->fetch_field()){
          if($col->acctype == 'customer'){
          Header("Location: user/dashboard.php");
        }else{
           Header("Location: other/dashboard.php");
        }
       }
    }
```

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for the formatting fix there. Didn't catch that.